# Running the same parameterized SQL query multiple times with different parameter values

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a parameterized SQL query, which reads parameter from the cell within Excel 2010  sheet.
If I need to run the same query for a few times (say for each quarter of a year) and store the results within the same workbook (i.e. 4 sheets, Q1, Q2,Q3 and Q4), do I need to create 4 (because there are 4 quarters) data connections?
Or is there a better solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload what you have tried yet ? So How can we suggest things

Comment: I have an Excel file with a date being entered by a user in cell F2. When Refresh button is clicked the following code is run pulling data from SQL Server.  
Private Sub Refresh_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim DateEnd As String
    DateEnd = Sheets("Report").Range("F2").Value
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TestConnection").OLEDBConnection
      .CommandText = "EXEC dbo.spReport @DateEnd='" & DateEnd & "'"
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("TestConnection").Refresh
    End With
    End Sub

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum, trying to figure out to present information better?!

Answer (score 0):

Generally no, you needn't. If your queries retrieve data from the same SQL server and use the same credentials, they can share the same connection.

Comment: I have only 1 query and 1 connection. But want to have N number of sheets that will show the results of the same query but with N different values of the same parameter. How to ensure that when I refresh sheet 1 with one value listed on sheet 1, sheet N with value on sheet N does not get refreshed using sheet 1 value? Does this make sense what I am trying to explain?

Comment: It should be ensured by your VBA script. Iterate over sheets and execute SQL query for every sheet for example. Or may be you can create  a single request which will return resultset containing a separate row for every sheet.